# window.blur not working anyhow

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a window open in the blur but it is not working.

Basically What I want is easy as I guessed.

There are two windows - 
1. On which I will open another window from.
2. New window which will get opened.

```
 var meds= {
     currentWindow:window,
     Window:''
 };

   meds.Window = window.open('http://www.meds.com',"com_meds._Code");
    meds.Window.blur();
    window.focus(); //setting focus on current window
```

But this is not working. I have tried many other similar solutions but nothing seems to work.

Please help!

Comment: a newly opened window should be noticed by user. I think what you are trying to achieve is not a user friendly experience at all.

Comment: @Manoz how do you know that was a typo?

Comment: @Manoz, sry I forgot to include a snippet above. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Please see edited answer.

Comment: @Manoz right, it should be, but that could be an error that the OP is making which affects the code. Don't fix problems in questions - ask the OP to clarify them.